# discord-buttons : Wondering how I can repeatedly edit a previous reply using a button

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

I am adding a baking minigame to my bot. It's where you follow along different instructions provided by the bot to create an item.

I would like to know how I can edit my bot's previous message to match the progress of one of the steps. In this case, you need to crack eggs into a bowl by clicking the button. I'm trying to make it so the message the bot sends updates your progress each time you crack an egg until you reach the quota.

```
var itemNames = args.join(' ').toLowerCase();
            console.log(itemNames)

            if ((itemNames === "cupcakes") || (itemNames === "cupcake")) {

                const eggsButton = new MessageButton()
                    .setLabel("Crack Eggs!")
                    .setStyle("blurple")
                    .setID("cupcakesStepOne")

                const cupcakesStepOne = await message.channel.send("Cupcakes, ok! Don't mess this up, dummy... We need to start with the eggs, why don't you crack a few into that bowl? **0 / 4**", eggsButton)
                var eggs = 0

                client.on('clickButton', async (button) => {
                    if (button.id === "cupcakesStepOne") {
                        button.reply.defer();
                        eggs = eggs + 1
                        console.log(eggs)
                        if (eggs = 1) {
                            cupcakesStepOne.edit("Cupcakes, ok! Don't mess this up, dummy... We need to start with the eggs, why don't you crack a few into that bowl? **1 / 4**")
                        } else {
                            if (eggs = 2) {
                                cupcakesStepOne.edit("Cupcakes, ok! Don't mess this up, dummy... We need to start with the eggs, why don't you crack a few into that bowl? **2 / 4**")
                            } else {
                                if (eggs = 3) {
                                    cupcakesStepOne.edit("Cupcakes, ok! Don't mess this up, dummy... We need to start with the eggs, why don't you crack a few into that bowl? **3 / 4**")
                                } else {
                                    if (eggs = 4) {
                                        cupcakesStepOne.edit("Cupcakes, ok! Don't mess this up, dummy... We need to start with the eggs, why don't you crack a few into that bowl? **4 / 4**")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Also, if I could organise this command better, please let me know! I'm still learning JavaScript and am merely an amateur when it comes to this sort of stuff.

Comment: Can you please tell which package you are using as the `clickButton` event is not a discord.js event.

Comment: I am using discord-buttons, you can find it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-buttons. My fault for not mentioning, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should put the event listener outside the `message` event listener of discord.js. In my opinion it is smart to use a Map to save the eggs in by the message id. It will look like this:

```
const buttons = require('discord-buttons');

const client = new Discord.Client();

buttons(client);

const cupcakes = new Map();

client.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.author.bot || message.channel.type === `dm`) return;

    if(!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;

    let args = message.content.substring("!".length).split(" ");

    var itemNames = args.join(' ').toLowerCase();
    console.log(itemNames)

    if (itemNames === "cupcakes" || itemNames === "cupcake") {

        const eggsButton = new buttons.MessageButton()
        .setLabel("Crack Eggs!")
        .setStyle("blurple")
        .setID("cupcakesStepOne")

        message.channel.send("Cupcakes, ok! Don't mess this up, dummy... We need to start with the eggs, why don't you crack a few into that bowl? **0 / 4**", eggsButton).then(msg => {
            cupcakes.set(msg.id, 0);
        });
    }
});

client.on('clickButton', async (button) => {
    if (button.id === "cupcakesStepOne") {
        if(!cupcakes.get(button.message.id)) return;
        cupcakes.set(button.message.id, cupcakes.get(button.message.id) + 1);
        const eggs = cupcakes.get(button.message.id);
        if(eggs <= 4){
            button.message.edit(`Cupcakes, ok! Don't mess this up, dummy... We need to start with the eggs, why don't you crack a few into that bowl? **${eggs} / 4**`);
            await button.reply.defer();
            if(eggs === 4) cupcakes.delete(button.message.id);
        } else await button.reply.defer();
    }
});
```